# Python как считать переход на новую строку?

Tags: python

Можно ли вообще считывать переход на новую строку? И если можно, то как?
Данные находятся в строке (*большой кусок текста, где присутствует переход на новую строку*), надо разделить большой кусок на много "однострочных"строк, либо в список.

Comment: Откуда вы читаете? Добавьте в вопрос текущий код для чтения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант:

```
text = '''
    Hello World !
    Hello World 1!
    Hello World 2 !
    Hello World 3  !
    Привет
    Привет 2
'''

newtext = text.splitlines()
print(newtext)
```